# Как сделать окно в котором будет отображаться сайт

Tags: python, веб-программирование, pyqt

Как сделать окно в котором будет отображаться сайт: https://www.old-games.ru/catalog/?platform=1&sort=popularity, но в этом окне мне не нужна адресная строка, а нужно чтобы были кнопки вернуться, и вперёд, и ещё чтоб можно было скачивать файлы.

Заранее спасибо!
[image: вот так выглядит]